# Existing Google Map update using PHP

Tags: php, google-maps

We have an existing Google Map that is manually edited and updated with new markers and poly-lines. The map is used in tracking a YWAM medical ship.

We want to automate some of the functions by using a PHP script (web page) to add new markers and poly-lines to the existing map when new data becomes available.

Is it possible to add new data to an existing map using a PHP script?

What Google Maps API is used to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried combining a manually-edited "My Maps"-style map with computer generated points, but I believe this is possible with the FusionTables api: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/sample_code#FTLayers

Comment: Thanks. That does look like what I need. I will have a good read.

Comment: Now I have found that I can't create a Table in Google Docs. There is no option for Table shown in the menu. 
Google shows lots of reference to an option Table (beta).